# How do I add a new line to my csv file using user inputs

Tags: python, csv

I need to write a new line to my CSV file with 2 inputs, therefore it will have 2 columns, username and password.

This is the current csv file

```
usernames,passwords
gary,password1
len,password2
```

however, I am trying to add new lines to it without editing the file itself.

I would like the program to ask for a username and a password then write them to the end of this file in the order username,password. Thanks

Comment: Try it yourself. If you have a specific problem you can ask here.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try with this code

```
import csv
import os
userName = input("Enter User Name: ")
passWord = input("Password: ")

fields = ['username','password']

filename = 'ur_filename.csv'

# Open file in append mode
with open(filename, 'a', newline='\n') as csvUser:

      # dict is now a dictionary, as required by writerow.
      dict = {'username': userName,'password': passWord}

      writer = csv.DictWriter(csvUser, fieldnames=fields)

      # if it's an empty file, write the header
      if os.stat(filename).st_size == 0:
          writer.writeheader()

      writer.writerow(dict)

csvUser.close()
```